# Using batch files to remove a single number from a folder name

Tags: batch-file

At work we use a bespoke program to search through a directory tree and find an individual image file. These files are stored in folders that have a 7-digit name, starting with '18' - so for instance '1873456', '1873457', '1873458' etc. The problem I have is at some point last year the procedure that creates these folders and populates the images in them reached '1899999' - and then rolled over to '18100000' and carried on like that for over 4,000 folders before it was caught and corrected.
The bespoke program we use can only handle seven-digit folder names. What I would like to do is create a batch file that renames all the eight-digit folders by removing the extra '1' in the name, so '18100000' becomes '1800000' and so forth until '18104013' becomes '1804013'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do the old 18nnnnn folders still exist? To rename 18100000 into 1800000, the later should not exist. What must be done if it exists?

Comment: @MC ND If you mean the older versions of '1800000' to '1899999', they're in a different folder. They were moved both to archive them and to save hard drive space on our server, so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in the base folder, it will not change any folders.

A file called `renfile.bat.txt` will be created that contains the rename command for the folders that match the filespec.  Examine it in notepad to see if it is ok and then rename it to renfile.bat and run it.

It's not tested.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r %%a in (18??????) do (
   set "name=%%~nxa"
   >>renfile.bat.txt echo ren "%%a" "!name:~0,2!!name:~3!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Foxi, this works almost like a charm. It runs through the directory and creates a rename command for each folder, however; but it's a simple matter to delete the lines I don't need and run the rest.

Comment: Bewdy.  If you change `18?` in the folderspec to `181` then it may target the folders better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for /l %%x in (100000,1,104013) do (
    set oldsuffix=%%x
    set newsuffix=%oldsuffix:~-5%
    ren 18%%x 18%newsuffix%
)
```

Comment: in this way will not work without delayed expasnions

Comment: This is not going to function over a directory tree either.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r "c:\somewhere" %%f in (181?????) do (
    set "name=0" & set /a "name+=%%~nf" 2>nul
    if !name! gtr 1899999 ren "%%~ff" "18!name:~-5!"
)
```